# How to add randomness or variability to Action Strip scale

Tags: scripting, drivers, nla-editor

I would like to add variability to an Action Strip's scale, ideally within a range of values I select.

In the wing beat strip below, for example, I would like to scale between something like .3 and .5 with a curve... or noise, or something. This variability is not within the individual actions contained in the AStrip: rather it adjusts the scale of the strip throughout its repeat range.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to set key frames for that value, so as a last resort I wrote a little python script.  Copy this into the text editor, and click "run script". Be sure to set the **MIN** and **MAX** values, and put the name of the action in the **ACTION_NAME** variable.  The script will automatically choose a new random value every time you change frame.  Setting the **STEP** size will make it wait n number of frames before choosing a new value.

```
import bpy
from random import random

# Set your min and max values here
MAX = 9
MIN = 3
ACTION_NAME = "DragonflyAction"

# Set step size.  Step size of 1 chooses a new value every frame
STEP = 5


def my_handler(scene):

    if scene.frame_current % STEP == 0:
        obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        obj.animation_data.nla_tracks["NlaTrack"].strips[ACTION_NAME].scale = (random() * (MAX - MIN)) + MIN

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While blender doesn't make it easy to add a keyframe or driver to the NLA strip's scale, it is posible to create a driver by typing one directly into the value. You can type a simple driver to create it and then edit the driver once it has been created.

With most editable values in blender we can press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert keyframes, we can also type a driver expression straight into the value if we precede it with a `#` as in entering `#frame` will create a driver that uses the current frame for the value. For a random value you can enter `#noise.random()*12+10` to get a random value between 10 and 22.

You can manually add a keyframe (or [driver](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58925/935)) using python -

```
strip = obj.animation_data.nla_tracks['NlaTrack'].strips['DragonflyAction']
strip.scale = 0.35
strip.keyframe_insert('scale', frame=1)
```

Having said that - a better option would be to add noise to the initial animation and not to the NLA strip settings. In the graph editor you can add a noise modifier to each animated value.

[image: noise modifier in use]

Comment: I didn't realize you could add drivers just by typing in the value.  That's pretty cool.

Comment: This is great.... and noise within a strip is cool, but not what I need here: The goal is to have repeating actions contained within the strip to repeat at a varying scale -- so a four-beat wing pattern repeating in 10 frames, then 15, then 9... But the cue on creating drivers is great!